# Bathtub drain top insert stopper stuck

Tags: drain, bathtub

How do I know for sure if this section where crossmember is that it's supposed to come out?
I've twisted a wrench on trying to use that crossmember to turn counter clockwise.
So far I heated it up with a plumbers torch, used bolt blaster on it.
My next thought is to invest in a tub drain tool and or extractor tool. Which tool I get depends on if that crossmember is part of what needs to come out. I can see slight line above that making me think it's part of drain under tub meant to stay...
every you tube I've seen shows crossmember on part that comes out from top of tub.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how old this tub might be?

Comment: original installed in 1972 when house built. Bathroom remodel just completed & this is one of last steps to replace with matte black pop up stopper.

Comment: Starting to think I need to cut it out with small hacksaw and or Dremel. After two nights of letting more bolt blaster soak in it's still not moving.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure since designs have changed so much over the years.  The only way to know for sure is to look at the underside of the tub.  You'll likely have to get under there anyway to install the new one.